# Getting "geometry" from google API result

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson

So far with the code I have, I am able to get results as a JsonObject. However, I am trying to get the coordinates of the location based on the postal code that I have entered. How can I retrieve the "lat" and "lng" as Strings/JsonElements? Would really appreciate if you can give me some insight. Thanks!

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    //the JSON builder
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        String restaurant = request.getParameter("r");
        String customer = request.getParameter("c");

        //Get coordinates of the restaurant 
        String longLatApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + restaurant;
        URL url = new URL(longLatApi);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", longLatApi);

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        String jsonString = builder.toString();
        JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

        out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
```

Comment: `JsonObject` has a bunch of methods to iterate through `obj`.

Comment: Yes, I can't seem to get the right one. I am able to get "results" but from there, I am unable to find the right method to get "geometry"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonElement` and its subclasses have nice methods to iterate through JSON elements of different kinds: `null`, a primitive (numbers, string literals, and booleans), a JSON object, or a JSON array. Knowing an exact structure of the response JSON document, you can extract child elements pretty straight-forward:

```java
final URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Greenwich");
// Let Gson parse the JSON input stream without expensive intermediate strings
try ( final Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())) ) {
    final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    // Extract the `results` array
    final JsonArray resultsJsonArray = jsonParser.parse(reader)
            .getAsJsonObject()
            .get("results")
            .getAsJsonArray();
    // Iterate over each result array element
    for ( int i = 0; i < resultsJsonArray.size(); i++ ) {
        final JsonObject resultJsonObject = resultsJsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(resultJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("formatted_address").getAsString());
        // Picking up the `geometry` property as a JSON object
        final JsonObject geometryJsonObject = resultJsonObject.get("geometry").getAsJsonObject();
        // And dumping the location
        final JsonObject locationJsonObject = geometryJsonObject.get("location").getAsJsonObject();
        dumpLocationJsonObject("Location", locationJsonObject);
        final JsonElement boundsJsonElement = geometryJsonObject.get("bounds");
        // There can be a `bounds` object with two additional properties
        if ( boundsJsonElement != null && !boundsJsonElement.isJsonNull() ) {
            final JsonObject boundsJsonObject = boundsJsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            dumpLocationJsonObject("North/East", boundsJsonObject.get("northeast").getAsJsonObject());
            dumpLocationJsonObject("South/West", boundsJsonObject.get("southwest").getAsJsonObject());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
private static void dumpLocationJsonObject(final String name, final JsonObject location) {
    final double latitude = location.getAsJsonPrimitive("lat").getAsDouble();
    final double longitude = location.getAsJsonPrimitive("lng").getAsDouble();
    System.out.println("\t" + name + ": (" + latitude + "; " + longitude + ")");
}
```

The output:

```
Greenwich, London SE10, UK  
    Location: (51.48257659999999; -0.0076589)
```

As an alternative approach, you can define custom JSON to Java classes mappings in order to deserialize the JSON document as a custom class instance, and not just `JsonElement` (something like `gson.fromJson(reader, customType)`). Both approaches have pros and cons.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me so much